# What happens when a member of the away team scores a hat trick in NHL?

Tags: ice-hockey, scoring, nhl

When a member of the home team scores a hat trick, it is normal for fans to throw their hats on the ice (usually causing a delay).  Does the same apply for when a member of the away team scores a hat trick?  Is it 'frowned' upon to throw your hat on the ice if you are cheering for the away team ?

Comment: Just curious, what happens with the hats? Do they throw them back? :)

Comment: Actually I am pretty sure they collect them and then donate them to a local charity

Comment: Could be, never seen it happen, but don't follow ice hockey aside from a few nhl play off games a year and got curious :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on circumstances.

The general rule is a fan will not throw a hat should a player from the opposing team score a hat trick. So, for the most part, nothing will happen.

However, depending on how many away fans are at the arena, you may see some of them throw hats on the ice.

Normally the hats are scraped off and donated.

Comment: I would also say that there might be other circumstances that are the exception to the rule; for example, if a well known superstar did it, you'd probably get a few hats, and if a well known superstar in his retirement year did it, you might get a lot.  Or if a player who was just traded in good terms (say if Brandon Saad came to Chicago and scored one), you'd probably have some.  But on balance, it wouldn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

In the NHL nowadays, there will be fans of the away team present in the arena.  Therefore it is possible that hats will be thrown onto the ice if someone from the away team scores a goal.

The hats are usually scraped away and donated to charity.  But this does not happen very often since hat tricks are not scored every day.

Comment: Pier welcome to SE.Sport the answer would be more effective if you insert any link or references on what you have written